# Firebase signInWithPopup function does not return correct error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, next.js, firebase-authentication, try-catch

I have this following code for retrieving user data with Facebook provider. I encountered an error, regarding users already stored with the same credentials.

Furthermore, I found a solution, implemented it, but it depends on the parameter error.

It should be an object, Firebase documentation even [says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth?hl=en&authuser=0#signinwithpopup) it should be an object.

Has anyone encountered this problem ?
It is really bugging me out.

```
async loginWithFacebook() {
    try {
      const userCred = await signInWithPopup(
        this.auth,
        new FacebookAuthProvider()
      );
      return {
        user: userCred.user,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      return {
        error: "Some error occured",
      };
    }
  }
```

I tried to use a different sign in method, but nothing changed.